# why is Next() method called next?

Tags: c#, random

Why does `Random.Next()` have Next in it's name? I know what it does, but the name doesn't seem to correspond to it.

Comment: `Random` is a random number generator. It does not generate one, but an infinite sequence of random numbers.

Comment: What should it be called then?  `Random.GetOne()`? How about `Random.Random()`? Maybe [`Random.Nine()`](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns the next number in the infinite sequence of numbers generated from your `Random` instance's seed.

Answer (score 1):

In computer science jargon, a "generator" is a specific kind of function: one that returns a different result each time it is called. It is traditional to call this function something like `next()`, because they are often used to return the next piece of a sequence (perhaps infinite). RNGs are just a special case of generator function, returning the next value in a calculated sequence.